# htaccess rewrite RegEx add static value between parameters

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to rewrite url's with htaccess. The request url length is variable.
It consists of the following:

http://**[domain.com]**/**[countrycode]**/**[main-category]**/**[sub-category]**/**[sub-sub-category]**/**[product-name]**.html

Of course it could also have less categories.

Another option is only a product page, like:
http://**[domain.com]**/**[countrycode]**/**[product-name]**.html

I want to rewrite these url's and add a static value between the [countrycode] and the rest of the url path. Also, I want to change .html to .aspx at the end of every rewritten URL.

I came as far as being able to rewrite a url with only the main category like:
http://example.com/en/main-category with this htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ https://example.com/$1/3/$2.aspx [R=301]
```

But if the url contains a trailing slash or more categories, the static value ("3") gets added in the wrong place.

to be clear, I want this structure:

request: http://example.com/en/main-category/sub-category/product-name.html

rewritten: https://example.com/en/3/main-category/sub-category/product-name.aspx

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this rule in site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/(?!3/)(.+)\.html$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/3/$2.aspx [L,NC,NE,R=301]
```

Comment: Edited your example to fit my needs. Working great.